# How do I control some nodes on a slide to be transparent at some times and visible on others?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have a slide with three `node` elements on them, with some math written in each. I want to control their visibility and transparency in the following way. The first slide shows the top node fully, the second slide makes it transparent, the third slide shows the node right below it (keeping the top node still transparent....), the fourth slide makes this node transparent, the next slide shows the final node, and the next slide again shows the top node fully. While the nodes are transparent, I want the math also to become transparent. I am unable to get any kind of transparency to work "on order".

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns, positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes,
                tikzmark
                }
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
%\usepackage{fourier,erewhon}
%\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}


\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}

\begin{frame}[t]{Applications: An Example} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, 
        optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = myblue,
            fill= myyellow,
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center
        }
        ]

        \draw node[below right=1 cm and 0.3cm of current page.north west, style=optimization problem] (prob)
        {
        $
        \begin{array}{ll}
        \textup{minimize} & \mu \\
        \textup{subject to} & F(\mu) = 0.
        \end{array}
        $
        };


        \draw node [below right= 3.5 cm and .3 cm of current page.north west, align=center, style=optimization problem, visible on = <3->] (mcP) 
        {
            \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
                problem description\\

                $
                \begin{array}{ll}
                \textup{maximize} & y \\
                \textup{subject to} & g(y)\geq 0.      
                \end{array}
                $
            \end{minipage}      
        };

        \draw node [right= 1.2cm of mcP, align=center, style=optimization problem, visible on = <4->] (mcD) 
        {
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                problem description - 2\\

                $
                \begin{array}{ll}
                \textup{minimize} & x \\
                \textup{subject to} & f(x)<= 0.         
                \end{array}
                $
            \end{minipage}      
        };

        \draw [<->, visible on = <4->] (mcP)--(mcD); 
        \draw[thick,->,shorten >=1pt, visible on = <5->] (mcD) to [out=90,in=0,loop,looseness=1] (prob);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first recall how `visible on` works. Its definition can be found in the `overlay-beamer-styles` library, and reads

```
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
}
```

So one can define an analogon thereof by

```
\tikzset{sort of visible/.style={opacity=0.3,text opacity=0.3},
fully visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{sort of visible}}}
```

which can be used as in

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns, positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes,
                tikzmark
                }
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
%\usepackage{fourier,erewhon}
%\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}


\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
% modifications of 
% \tikzset{
%     invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
%     visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
% }
% from overlay-beamer-styles

\tikzset{sort of visible/.style={opacity=0.3,text opacity=0.3},
fully visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{sort of visible}},}
\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}

\begin{frame}[t]{Applications: An Example} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, 
        optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = myblue,
            fill= myyellow,
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center
        }
        ]

        \draw node[below right=1.5 cm and 1cm of current page.north west, 
        fully visible on=<{1,5}>,
        style=optimization problem] (prob)
        {
        $
        \begin{array}{ll}
        \textup{minimize} & \mu \\
        \textup{subject to} & F(\mu) = 0.
        \end{array}
        $
        };


        \draw node [below right= 4 cm and 1 cm of current page.north west, 
        align=center, style=optimization problem, 
        text width=.42\textwidth,
        fully visible on = <3->] (mcP) 
        {%
            %\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
                problem description\\
                $
                \begin{array}{ll}
                \textup{maximize} & y \\
                \textup{subject to} & g(y)\geq 0.      
                \end{array}
                $
           % \end{minipage}      
        };

        \draw node [right= 1.2cm of mcP, align=center, 
        style=optimization problem,
        text width=.42\textwidth,
        fully visible on = <4->] (mcD) 
        {%
            %\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                problem description - 2\\
                $
                \begin{array}{ll}
                \textup{minimize} & x \\
                \textup{subject to} & f(x)<= 0.         
                \end{array}
                $
            %\end{minipage}      
        };

        \draw [<->, visible on = <4->] (mcP)--(mcD); 
        \draw[thick,->,shorten >=1pt, visible on = <5->] (mcD) to [out=90,in=0,loop,looseness=1] (prob);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

to give

[image]

Please note that I also made some off-topic changes. For instance, the `minipage`s can be traded for `text width`, and you need also `overlay` to make use of anchors like `current page.north west` without getting asked to recompile infinitely often.

Comment: As usual, fantastic answer! Could you tell me where you were able to access the innards of tikzset? I scoured the beamer and pgf manuals, but I couldn't find the two lines you posted at the very beginning of your answer. Thank you for teaching me so much!

Comment: @lazulikid I just look up the libraries. (I wrote a command on my machine that shows the contents of a given library. The implementation is crappy, I think, but it works, so all I did was to type `ShowLib.pl overlay-beamer-styles` which then did a `less /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/aobs-tikz/tikzlibraryoverlay-beamer-styles.code.tex`. I wouldn't be surprised if there were much better commands of that sort was available, as I said mine isn't very good and tailored to my MacOs TeXLive installation.)